# Down-voting instead of re-formatting

Tags: discussion, down-votes, markdown

It is just something that really irks me. I'm not particularly bothered in the slightest about reputation or whatever; it's more a lack of willingness to help (because it doesn't happen on my questions).

When people post a question which is poorly formatted or in broken English (though understandable), it gets down-voted, even if it is a *good* question.

Why do people insist on just being lazy and downvoting instead of reformatting the question themselves? It seems ridiculous that people will come on this site to ask a decent question, they actually post their code, error and the whole 'what-have-you-tried' stuff, and get down-voted because they haven't formatted properly or can't speak English very well.

I think there should be some rules in place that stops people just posting "Reformat it, it's messy at the moment."

Also, this stops the question from getting attention, as when 3 or 4 people down-vote it, and somebody else reformats it, no one will look at it due to the -4 it now has.

Comment: SO gets 4,000 new questions a day. That's one reason why not every question gets reformatted. And in my experience, formatting problems are usually accompanied by more serious ones as well. I rarely see downvoting occurring when formatting is the *only* problem a question has. Can you show an example?

Comment: Why do people insist on being lazy and posting barely coherent questions with broken formatting? While encouraged, it's not our duty to clean up after people who don't make an effort.

Comment: @Madmartigan Oh christ, that irks me too. For a community with such expansive knowledge, they really don't know how to look after people with a looser grasp of english or who don't know what JSFiddle is. It takes 2 seconds to paste the code over.

Comment: As said in my personal experience, this rarely happens. Can you show an example?

Comment: @Pekka I understand that, but why downvote it? It's futile because the question will go unanswered and will either be reposted, or you've lost another user. I can show an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737264/which-steps-can-i-take-to-remove-the-error-in-my-code

Comment: @lunboks Sorry, I forget everyone needs to be a pro at using the site before they can post a question. If they can barely speak English, I doubt they can read it that well either. And the formatting options on SO aren't exactly the most intuitive.

Comment: @JoshuaM In that example, the question was terribly formatted (No language barrier issue there). Someone corrected it for the OP and there is a question to correct the formatting. Perhaps not the best example?

Comment: I don't know anything about Cocoa nor Objective-C, but your example doesn't strike me as a particularly good question - it looks like a very basic "plz debug my code for me" that many frown upon. I'd say it's not certain whether the formatting really caused the downvotes

Comment: @Bart It had -4 I think before someone corrected it? I'm not saying that it wont be reformatted, I'm _saying_ it takes time, gets the downvotes and is then too late for the question to be noticed. Pekka And "plz debug my code" isn't always so bad, its what most questions here are when something doesnt work? thats what we're here for right? It doesn't work and I can't fix it. Also, the only comment is based on the formatting, and it hit -4 before formatting.

Comment: @JoshuaM - No, we explicitly _are not_ a "here's my code, what's wrong" debugging service.

Comment: Of course not, but what do you spend much of your time doing? Debugging Code.

Comment: @Joshua sometimes we end up doing a one-on-one debugging session while answering a question, that's correct - you answer a question but it doesn't help the OP, you ask for details, they tell you what happens, you ask for more details, etc. Still, "my code doesn't work" requests are not welcome here, and some people (myself often included) will downvote them. That's more likely to be the reason for the voting than the formatting.

Comment: @JoshuaM cause they are don't bother to read FAQ (that is about formatting and some necessarily things) before asking questions. Moreover there is often violations in TOS (and that is why we have questions with *debug my code*) that you **have to** read and agree before asking first question.
We are here to help you (not you literally), but if you are not put effort in asking a proper question and breaking the rules, you got downvoted.

Comment: I have to agree with Pekka - this looks like "plz debug my code for me". I tend to downvote questions containing a wall of code and it has nothing to do with formatting. Narrowing down the problem before posting a question really shouldn't be too much to expect - after all, he is asking us to spend time on his problem, it is reasonable for him to spend some time on it himself first.

Comment: How can you say someone is being lazy for not doing something they weren't responsible for doing in the first friggen place?

Comment: @Won't ...because it's an opinion? :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Personally, I only put the time and effort in to cleaning up either:

- Posts that *I* find *interesting*
- Posts that *I* find *helpful*
- Posts that others seem to find helpful and seem like *good* questions

A *good* question being one where the OP clearly put in effort to solve the problem on their own, took the time to explain what they tried and what didn't work, explained what results they were expecting to get, explained *why* they are trying to do what they are, etc.

The questions I edit also often get an upvote from me as well, since I find them useful.

I *do* also engage in "drive-by-downvoting" if:

- The OP clearly didn't try to put together a clear question
- The OP is just looking for someone to do their work for them for free
- Someone else has already commented on what the issue is
- The OP clearly didn't do any sort of "self-help", even as basic as a google search, prior to posting
- The post is too chaotic for me to have any reasonable understanding of what the OP is after
- The OP has posted similar crap before (yes, I *do* look at profiles from time to time to determine my behavior)

Depending on what mood I'm in, it might take only one of these criteria, or it might take a number of them, but in *most* cases, questions that I  "drive-by-downvote" are simply *not* good questions.

I typically will leave a comment explaining the issue, but I tend not to if I'm in a foul mood.

Comment: Moreover, even if it will cost to OP to spend another 10 minutes to clarify the answer, he will save about an hour of other developers time (assuming 1 minute to look at the question and with average of about 60 views).

Comment: @om-nom-nom, Yes, that's a very good point.

Comment: Now that's fair enough. Like I say, it irks _me_ personally, was just voicing the opinion because this is the place to do it!

Comment: @JoshuaM, and I was, likewise, responding with _my_ opinion to help you with your frustration and perhaps give another perspective. Isn't the Internet great!

Comment: @cdeszaq, it is indeed a source of a fantastic range of people and opinions.

Answer (score 13):

To stay strictly on-topic:

> Why do people insist on just being lazy and downvoting instead of reformatting the question themselves?

If the formatting is clearly due to a misunderstanding of how to highlight code in markdown, and all I have to do is highlight it and hit CTRL+K or remove some inline backticks, then I will gladly do so. I will not downvote for this.
If any combination of the following are true:

- The code is still unreadable after I highlight it
- Tons of unnecessary spaces in the code
- Lots of code that is *clearly* irrelevant to the question
- I feel obligated to also fix several spelling and grammar errors, tags, title, etc.
- The user experienced enough on SO that they should know how to format a question by now
- I've noticed a trend of poor questions from the user

Then I will probably downvote. I don't consider downvoting "lazy", and I don't feel that anyone should be obligated to edit someone else's post. I *do* think it's lazy to post a question that looks like crap because you didn't bother to use the preview or look at your post after it went live.

Comment: The point about not looking at the preview or at what you just posted is critical.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but I can't get on board with this. It seems wrong to downvote for spelling mistakes after you correct them. If there's something intrinsically wrong with the question (e.g. it's a plzsendtehcodez), then fine, but you didn't mention that.

Comment: @PopularDemand: I almost edited to clarify that: Spelling or grammar related to language differences is not what I mean, it's stuff like *no* punctuation, ALL CAPS, txtspeak like *"smth"*, *"u"*, *"btw"*, things that clearly show a lack of effort, not knowledge: and still, that alone is not enough to warrant a DV. I hope you understand.

Comment: I don't see the difference... a post's score is supposed to indicate its quality, not the author's behavior. Therefore, if a post gets fixed up, downvoting for its past problems is semantically wrong. That said, I _have_ given out "good job learning to use the site, new user!" upvotes and "by 5000 rep you should know not to ask plzsendtehcodez questions" downvotes, but only on questions that deserved them or were borderline to begin with.

Comment: @PopularDemand: I think that's fair and I agree. I can't see any reason to downvote a quality post after the title, tags, spelling, grammar, and formatting has been corrected, I suppose I was just firing off a list of things that annoy me, which was rather off-topic. Of course, these things *usually* aren't associated with otherwise good quality questions.